# How to input a long number and output phone numbers in java?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Given a long integer representing a 10-digit phone number, output the area code, prefix and line number using the format `(800) 555-1212`.

Ex: If the input is: `8005551212`

The output is: `(800) 555-1212`

I am stuck here.

**My Code:**

```
package MyLabs;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyLabs17 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            long phoneNumber;
            phoneNumber = scnr.nextLong(); //user will input number here
            long lineNumber = phoneNumber % 10000; //the last 4 digits of phone
            long areaCode = phoneNumber / 10000000; // the first 3 digits of phone.
            long prefix = areaCode % 1000;  // this is where I'm going wrong. How do I get the 3 middle numbers?
             
           System.out.println("(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + prefix + "-" + lineNumber );
           // example: when I input number 8005551212, the output I get is: (800) 800-1212!
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If `areaCode` is the three leftmost digits, how can you expect to get the prefix from that?

Comment: Honestly the easiest would probably to just convert the integer to a string first.

Comment: You can take input in String

Comment: If you just want the math, I think something like `(phoneNumber / 10000) % 1000` will extract the middle digits of the area code.

Comment: You don't actually ask a question here. What part is not working? What hav you done? Every IDE out there has excellent debugging interfaces. Have you tried stepping through the code and see where it goes wrong?

Comment: Yes i did. Thankfully somebody helped me out here ;) You probably didn't even read the message, just judged lol

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
long phoneNumber = 8005551212L;
String formatted = ("" + phoneNumber).replaceAll("(...)(...)(....)", "($1) $2-$3");
System.out.println(formatted);
```

output

```
(800) 555-1212
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use Strings in this case. It's far easier.

```
try (Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    long input = scnr.nextLong();
    String phoneNumber = Long.toString(input);
    String areaCode = phoneNumber.substring(0, 3);
    String prefix = phoneNumber.substring(3, phoneNumber.length() - 4);
    String lineNumber = phoneNumber.substring(phoneNumber.length() - 4);

    System.out.println("(" + areaCode + ")" + " " + prefix + "-" + lineNumber);
}
```

Comment: Instead for `long input = scnr.nextLong();
    String phoneNumber = Long.toString(input)
    long input = scnr.nextLong();
    String phoneNumber = Long.toString(input);;`

Comment: I don't agree with you. A solution without Strings is better.